# How to make Bootstrap5 Columns all a similar height?

Tags: html, css, height

I'm using Bootstrap5. However, I'd just like to make a similar height of these two columns. How can I do that?
Here's the Code:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div style="background-color:LightGray" class="container-1 col-xs-6" >
        Cake
        <img src="https://www.mybakingaddiction.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/lr-0953.jpg" alt="Cake"/>
<div style="background-color:Gray" class="container-2 col-xs-6">
        Content
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
  integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h2>Cake</h2>
    <div class="col-6">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="https://www.mybakingaddiction.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/lr-0953.jpg"
        alt="Cake" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-6" style="background-color:Gray">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h2>Cake</h2>
    <div class="col-6">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="https://www.mybakingaddiction.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/lr-0953.jpg" alt="Cake" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-6" style="background-color:Gray">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

col-xs-6 is not working in bootstrap5 so you can use col-6 instead of col-xs-6 and div closing and are used not properly